# php artisan commands not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, command, laravel-artisan

php artisan commands not working in laravel  but there is an error
##################################################################

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class request does not exist in C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('request')
#1 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('request')
#2 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('request', Array)
#3 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(732): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('request', Array)
#4 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('request', Array)
#5 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\help in C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 752

Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class request does not exist in C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('request')
#1 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('request')
#2 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('request', Array)
#3 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(732): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('request', Array)
#4 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('request', Array)
#5 C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\help in C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 752

############################################################################
than I use "  dd($exception);" in helper and this exception came up:
################################################################################
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError {#36
#message: "Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 67"
#code: 0
#file: "C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php"
#line: 102
#severity: E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
trace: {
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:102 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php:67 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:749 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:631 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:586 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:732 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:110 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:936 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\config\admin.php:25 {
› */
› 'logo' => '',
›
arguments: {
$path: "logo/logo-big-white.png"
}
}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php:71 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php:39 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:213 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:296 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:119 { …}
C:\xampp7.4\htdocs\blog\artisan:37 { …}
}
}

Comment: did you run `composer install`?

Comment: yes and same error!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using " url() " helper in blog\config\admin.php file, if that's the case comment / remove that or use env() to load url and run the artisan command again that should work

Comment: Have you tried "php artisan config:cache"  after removing url() helper?

Comment: Strange. Try to manually delete files from bootstrap/cache. And find and remove url() helper from other config files and try again